# How to make a pretty simple Codeigniter url route?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-3

I've looked some websites have a simple route in their login/registration form. For instance, their form redirect to `action="/function/method"`. Recenttly I want to implement that route in codeigniter (I use codeigniter 3), but my form still break. I don't know how to.

Below is my simple controller:

```
/*
* i.e Folder: Login
* i.e Controller name: Login
* i.e steps: login/login/verify
*/

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Load login view
    }

    public function verify()
    {
        // Processing data from login form
    }
}
```

And the login form is:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login/login/verify'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button class="btn btn-login" type="submit">Sign in</button></p>
</form>
```

As we can see the action is redirect to `base_url()/login/login/verify` or if we print this will make `http://localhost/domain/login/login/verify`. I think it's seem too long. What I want to is to simplify that route, for instance, `action="/login/verify"`. I try to make route `$route['login/(:any)'] = "login/login/$1"` and it's not working. A little trick maybe to rename login folder i.e `user`, so that will be `user/login/verify`. But it's not what I want to.

Any idea or direction?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a you're attempting to call a method that doesn't exit.

Remember that Codeigniter's URL Scheme is:
`http://localhost/codeigniter_installation/controller/method/params/..../`

From your question, you appear to be calling:

```
/login/login/verify
login - controller
login - method
verify - param
```

This would be listed as: `function login($action = "verify") { do_stuff() }` in your controller.

When you should just be calling: `/login/verify`

Comment: Excuse me, if I'm not misunderstanding, I just call `<form action="/login/verify" method="post"` after add parameter in login method in my view?

Comment: Well, to be correct you would use the ***url helper*** and do `<?= site_url('login/verify'); ?>`